# Can I have a program (Thunderbird) start running and minimized in the system tray when the PC starts?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using an app that named Thunderbird. It's an email client and it supports minimising to the system tray. Can I have this program start running in the system tray when the PC starts? The app has no such option.

When I put the shortcut of Thunderbird in the start folder, the application starts as a full screen window. I don't want this.

Can I have the application start minimized in the lower right corner when the computer boots up??

Comment: You can try Task Scheduler, but if the app will not start minimized then I do not think that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thunderbird addons to the rescue:

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/minimize-on-start-and-close/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/169437/how-to-start-thunderbird-minimized-on-start-up

Thunderbirds Are Go!

Comment: this addon is not up-to-date but after you send this link I found an alternative for this app: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/simple-startup-minimizer/ Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a command line argument to start minimized (or in the system tray).

But you could write a simple script.

For example in [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) it would look something like this:

```
Run("notepad.exe")
Sleep(2000)
Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)
WinSetState($hWnd, "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
```

In AutoHotKey it would be something like:

```
Run, notepad.exe
WinWait, Untitled - Notepad
WinMinimize
```

A good opportunity to learn a simple scripting language perhaps?